# Trying to retrieve from the Firestore Database not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to essentially use a query to retrieve data from the database that has the matching uid as the user logging in. Here is the json format for the users collection and what you would expect for the data:

```
email: "",
first: "",
last: "",
role: "Regular User" or "Admin User",
uid: which is the uid generated when creating a new user so they're tied.
```

I'm trying to use this code where during log in it would also retrieve the role data so I can use it for future reference but I'm only ever outputting undefined.

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(userCred => {
        setErrorMessage(null);
        const user = userCred.user;
        console.log(user.uid);

        //User Role check
        const userRef = collection(db, 'users');
        const q = query(userRef, where("uid", "==", user.uid));
        
        onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
          let users = [];
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            users.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
          })
          console.log(users);
        })
```

Just in case people need the context this is how I set up firebase in a separate config file:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a fix through a long hard fought battle in the firebase documentation...

I found that using getDocs and passing the query there was also a valid solution to my problem:

```
const q = query(userRef, where("uid", "==", user.uid));

    getDocs(q)
      .then((qSnapshot) => {
        qSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data().role)
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
      })
```

Pretty sure I tried it before posting this question but it didn't work? No complaints since it finally did.